# angular @ngrx - redux where should i handle actions like export that don't change the state

Tags: angular, ngrx, reducers

I have an APP with an "Export" button. When clicked , the APP get from the server a big text file and 
uses the HTML5 blob API to "save as" so the user can save it to his disk

In order to start the export operation in dispatch export action

```
this.store.dispatch(new scanListsActions.Export(id));
```

this action is then handled by the "effects" code that goes to the backend server to grab the file.
when done, ExportSuccess action is dispatched.

Now, i don't want to store the file content in the store since it is very big,
on the other hand i need the data in the view in order to send it to the user.
currently you can see that i send it to the user in the reducer code (below).

How normally is it done? where is the place to hold the that sends the file to the user?

```
import * as fileSaver from 'file-saver'; // npm i --save file-saver

export function reducer(state: ScanListsState = initialState, action: ScanListsActions): ScanListsState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ScanListsActionTypes.Export:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            };

        case ScanListsActionTypes.ExportSuccess:

       // these 2 lines below send the file to the user (starts a download)
       // where should i put this code. I don't think the reducer is the place for it

            const blob = new Blob([action.payload.data], { type: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' });
            fileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'destination_list.txt');

            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: null
            };

        case ScanListsActionTypes.GeneralFail:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Effects code

```
@Injectable()
export class ScanListsEffects {

    constructor(private scanListService: ScanListService,
        private actions$: Actions) { }



    @Effect()
    exportScanList$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(scanListsActions.ScanListsActionTypes.Export),
        mergeMap((action: scanListsActions.Export) =>
            this.scanListService.getScanList(action.payload).pipe(
                map(sList => (new scanListsActions.ExportSuccess(sList))),
                catchError(err => of(new scanListsActions.GeneralFail(err)))
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a service call for your saving, just as you did for your read. In an effect you'd call the service:

Something like:

```js
    @Effect()
    fileSaveExportScanList$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(scanListsActions.ScanListsActionTypes.ExportSuccess),
        mergeMap((action: scanListsActions.ExportSuccess) =>
            this.scanListService.saveScanList(action.payload).pipe(
                map (() => (new scanListsActions.SaveSuccess())),
                catchError(err => of(new scanListsActions.GeneralFail(err)))
            )
        )
    );
```

and then have a service call 'saveScanList'

```js
     saveScanList(data: any){
            const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' });
            fileSaver.saveAs(list, 'destination_list.txt');
```

Comment: The method `this.scanListService.saveScanList` (I assume) talks to a backend to get the URL and if successful, use this URL to save the file. We don't know the URL ahead of time.

Comment: Reading functions are put into a service... how unclean/weird is it to then put writing functions in the components? the `this.scanListService.saveScanList` is responsible for the writing functions, making the txt file and storing it wherever, a location could be the backend.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you shouldn't be doing it in the reducer (at least I wouldn't). You should be doing it in the component itself.

You should store `action.payload.data` in the reducer in terms url or whatever key and react to it.

Something like this:

Your reducer state should look like:

```
export interface ScanListsState { 
 url: string; // (I assume string),
 loading: boolean;
 error: any; // You can put whatever interface you want
}
```

Everything else in your reducer is good, except in the case of `ScanListsActionTypes.ExportSuccess:` return:

```
return {
  ...state,
  url: action.payload.data,
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};
```

Then in your component

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.reactToURLChangesOfExport();
}
exportClicked() {
  this.store.dispatch(new scanListsActions.Export(id));
}
reactToURLChangesOfExport() {
  this.store.pipe(
   select(YourSelectorForTheSliceOfTheURL), // make a selector that will react to changes to the URL property of the slice of data in the store.
   // put a takeUntil or however you want to destroy this subscription so it prevents memory leaks
  ).subscribe(url => {
    const blob = new Blob([url], { type: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' });
    fileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'destination_list.txt');
  })
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't getting and saving data be done in a service, and shouldn't you call that service from an effect?

Comment: I think they are doing that, check their last snippet in their question (the code for the effect).

Comment: Scan seems like a read, and he's asking where to do the write: 'save to file', which should also be done in an effect I'd assume. he's probably getting data from a specific location and wants to save it to a .txt file

Comment: What w are doing is calling a service to get the data. the data is not a URL but a big chunk of text data , we get it from the server and i don't think we should save the data (1-2 MB) in the state

Comment: @MaayanHope Oh ok, sorry I misunderstood.